# how do version control services calculate used storage?

Tags: git, svn, cloud, price

I was looking for a online version control to be able to host a Game Project which is getting too big for Github's limit of 1GB , due to graphics and other multimedia content.

I came across sites like cloud forge , bitbucket etc. and they all offer roughly 10-15 GB of storage for a Git or SVN repository.

Does that storage limit indicates the size of the HEAD REVISION of the project or does it refer to all of the file/commit deltas and meta data as well?

I've worked on a few other games in different companies and they all preferred to have their version control hosted in their own office, I could not tell if the reason for this was the cost or security or both. But I do know that game projects tend to get insanely large (50GB+) during development, mostly due to large size of multimedia content such as textures , audio , animations etc.

So if the limit indicated is for size of storage with all the commit deltas then I wonder if any of those services are ever feasible for anyone with a large and ever growing project.

Comment: If you want to do game development with assets, you must use git-lfs. And github (for example) provide as many space as you want. It's just that you have to pay: https://help.github.com/articles/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage/#purchasing-additional-storage-and-bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

> Does that storage limit indicates the size of the HEAD REVISION of the
>   project or does it refer to all of the file/commit deltas and meta
>   data as well?

AFAIK the storage limit is about the size of actual repository on disk. Therefore, it's not about HEAD revision or a size of SVN working copy.

Note that SVN uses various [diskspace-saving techniques](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deltas) and supports [cheap copies](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/using/). Note that Subversion also supports xdelta compression algorithm that works for textual content and non-compressed binary data. If you change several bytes in a non-compressed multi-gigabyte binary file, Subversion needs only to store those bytes (plus metadata) for the new version of your file. Read SVNBook | How Subversion saves disk space for further information.

Read [SVNBook | How Subversion saves disk space](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deltas) for further information.